# Calculate different between ranges and find top 3 values without writing to workbook

Tags: arrays, vba, foreach

I am attempting to have my machine calculate the difference between two arrays of any length and return the 1,2,3 largest values. The code below works for a range which lives on a worksheet.

```
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Dim Value1 As Double, Value2 As Double, Value3 As Double
    Value1 = 0
    Value2 = 0
    Value3 = 0
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value > Value1 Then
            Value1 = cell.Value
            value1row = cell.Row
            value1col = cell.Column
        End If
    Next cell
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value > Value2 And cell.Value < Value1 Then
            Value2 = cell.Value
            Value2Row = cell.Row
            Value2Col = cell.Column
        End If
    Next cell
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value > Value3 And cell.Value < Value2 Then
            Value3 = cell.Value
            Value3Row = cell.Row
            Value3Col = cell.Column
        End If
    Next cell
```

Am I am able to store the calculated values in an array? And loop in the array with the above? How would I adjust the For Each Loop to read the array?

```
Dim CalcArray(1 to 100) as variant
For x = 1 to LastRow
CalcArray(x) = cells(i,1) - cells(i,2)
Next X
```

Also, how do we make the array size dynamic?